# Selecting rows limited to the most recent date

Tags: sql

I am a SQL novice, trying to figure out a way to pare down rows that basically gives me only one name per row, with the criteria being the latest "Encounter Date". I want to go from this:

```
    Measure_ID   Name   User    Encounter Date  Numerator
    NQF-0101      A      1           4/10/2015        0
    NQF-0101      A      1           4/11/2015        1
    NQF-0101      B      2           4/12/2015        1
    NQF-0101      B      2           4/13/2015        0
    NQF-0101      C      3           4/14/2015        1
    NQF-0101      C      3           4/15/2015        1
    NQF-0101      C      3           4/16/2015        1
```

To this:

```
   Measure_ID  Name  User    Encounter Date   Numerator
   NQF-0101     A     1           4/11/2015           1
   NQF-0101     B     2           4/13/2015           0
   NQF-0101     C     3           4/16/2015           1
```

Any thoughts on the type of SQL query I can run to make this happen? Thank you!

Comment: What dbms are you using?

Comment: SELECT * FROM table_name GROUP BY name ORDER BY encounter_date  ?

Comment: I'm actually using custom SQL in Tableau; I'm not sure if it is similar to other dbms.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL Server, or any other dbms that supports window function, you can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Measure_ID, User ORDER BY EncounterDate DESC)
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

---

If not, you can use the `MAX` function:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tbl t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        Measure_ID, User, MAX(EncounterDate) AS MaxDate
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY Measure_ID, User
) t2
    ON t1.Measure_ID = t2.Measure_ID
    AND t1.User = t2.User
    AND t1.EncouterDate = t2.MaxDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `User` and `Encounter Date` are unique, then

```
Select t.* 
from MyTable t
join (select User, max([Encounter Date]) as [Encounter Date] 
      from MyTable 
      group by User) q
on q.User= t.User and q.[Encounter Date] = t.[Encounter Date]
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to rank each row by the Encounter Date column, within a group based on the name column.

The `OVER()` clause partitions the table by the name column, and orders the rows within each partition by their Encounter Date.

```
SELECT
   measure_id
  ,name
  ,[user]
  ,encounter_date
  ,numerator
FROM(
  SELECT
     measure_id
    ,name
    ,[user]
    ,encounter_date
    ,numerator
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY encounter_date DESC) AS row_num
  FROM test
)q
WHERE row_num = 1
```

Using a subquery allows you to filter out everything except the most recent row.

Here is the example working in a sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ba10b/2